# Does anything bad happen to the cat in the film?

Tags: plot-explanation, inside-llewyn-davis

I would like to take my girlfriend to see this film but she is very sensitive about animals (especially cats) so if anything bad happens to the cat in this film then it would probably be best to avoid it. No need for details or spoilers, just let me know if there is any cat-related jeopardy.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is quite frankly ridiculous. Could be easily answered by viewing the movie. If it really is that bad then I'd suggest you either watch it yourself first or just pick another one.

Comment: So your suggestion is that I see the movie twice instead of asking for advice ? Thanks - very helpful...

Comment: Sorry for the rudeness, but it would just be much better suited for a site like Yahoo Answers. If it's not about analysing, or explaining a movie, character or actor, then it's off-topic.

Comment: @PaulR - As you well know, StackExchange sites have some strict rules on what constitutes a **good question**. Questions that can be answered with a bit of Googling or watching the actual film fall under the category of being too trivial. Thus the vote to close.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is very subjective and given that PETA and Animal Society is always required on set to certify cruelty free production, any harm is simulated not real. So is the concern about REAL harm, which wouldn't happen, or simulated is unacceptable too? This pretty much answers itself.

Comment: Though, while personally not so much in favour of this question, to your defense I also have to say that there is currently a not yet completely decided meta discussion going on about what to do with questions of exactly this kind, which you might want to have a look at or provide some valuable feedback to: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1131/49

Comment: @ChristianRau - I'm not sure this fits that. That is about phobias, this is a "I don't like this". Otherwise we'll get questions such as "I'm a Southern Baptist tee-totaler, do they drink at all in movie X?" and similar personal prejudice questions. Phobias are medical conditions that could potentially provoke quite strong physical and mental reactions that could ruin other moviegoers' experience.

Comment: @JohnP I don't like the question too much either, but I still think it's enough of a grey area to be at least very interesting for that meta discussion and vice versa (be it only just as a negative example).

Comment: @JohnP The meta question itself is certainly not just about phobias alone, even if the resulting policy (which isn't yet completely existing) might become to be.

Comment: I don't think phobia (which tends to imply irrationality) is the correct term - many people find it unpleasant to watch depictions of cruelty or suffering. Furthermore there are whole web sites dedicated to categorising films in terms of violence, sex, drugs, etc, so that parents can decide whether a film is appropriate for their children. My situation is somewhat similar - my girlfriend is uncomfortable with depictions of animal suffering, so I need to research films that might be problematic. I've tried asking on IMDB forums without any luck, so I tried here. Feel free to close if off-topic.

Comment: I think people can forget they are speaking to other people. Someone has come for *Help*. When this happens, all we should do is quit bickering and help them. After that, we can delete the question, but to attack them is just pushing people away from the site.

Comment: @JohnSmithOptional Just because they need help with something movie related doesn't mean it's automatically on topic.

Comment: @PaulR But on this site phobias are **the** valid reason for asking, and not because someone just thinks it's unpleasant. Like you said, there are other websites designed specifically to help with what you're looking for. This is not one of them.

Comment: @Tom: well no, that's the point - there are *not* web sites that cover depictions of animal cruelty in films - there are sites that cover the major things that parents might be concerned about, but nothing where I can find the info I need. I tried IMDB without success - what other sites do you suggest? Anyway, in this instance I got a helpful answer from John Smith Optional (thank you John) - feel free to close/delete the question since its mere presence obviously offends you.

Comment: @PaulR Well, if it's not on topic then it doesn't belong here. Simple as that. Again, sorry for the rudeness, a bit cranky today, but we've been getting more of these questions lately and they just don't belong here. Good luck elsewhere, though. If I ever run into a site of the kind you're looking for, I'll put it in a comment and tag you.

Comment: No problem - I don't normally hang out on movies.SE (I'm mainly a StackOverflow person) - I won't post any more questions like this here. FWIW I think the Help section needs to be a bit clearer about what is and is not on-topic here.

Comment: @Tom, I know your 'cranky', but I believe the priority on here should be *helping* people, first and foremost. There has been more written (to a factor of x22) in debate that was required to answer the question. That's insane. Help the guy, *then* shut it down if it's so horrific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implied, but not seen. That's as detail free an answer as they come!

The definitive answer you are loking for would be a spoiler to the film, as the cat's fate is a sub plot of the movie.

Comment: Thanks - it sounds like I might be able to take a chance on this one then, although I will hold you personally responsible if my GF is upset by it. ;-)

Comment: I can live with that! Its a great film though, so I wouldn't expect you both to be anything other than impressed.

Comment: Thanks - certainly looks very good from the trailers and reviews that I've seen.